# How to find the roots from a polynomial using columns from a dataframe

Tags: python

I'm having a problem trying to find the roots of a polynomial that involves multiple columns of a dataframe on python.

cp = ((u1+u4)(u1^2-u4^2))  /  2u1^3

I'm trying to find the real and positive roots of u4.

I have been able to find the roots using MATLAB but not sure how to find them using python. I've used the following code on python:

```
df['u4'] = np.roots([ 1/(2*df['u1']**3), 1/(2*df['u1']**2), -1/(2*df['u1']), df['cp'] - 1/2]);
```

This was the code I used on MATLAB:

```
u4 = roots([ 1/(2*u1^3), 1/(2*u1^2), -1/(2*u1), cp - 1/2]);
```

I get the ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array. If someone could help me out then that would be great.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python find roots of an equation", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to point out something from your code.

This: `df['u4']` means you are selecting the entire column of `u4` in your DataFrame and not the value within it or anything you've done under similar syntax, which means that `(2*df['u1']**3)` and so on would return an error.

If you are trying to compute for a value per entry of each column, you have to iterate it through the entire DataFrame and do the calculation per iterable.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):

  df['u4'][i] = np.roots([ 1/(2*df['u1'][i]**3), 1/(2*df['u1'][i]**2), -1/(2*df['u1'][i]), df['cp'][i] - 1/2])
```

I did not focus on the math (disclaimer :D). But basically what this does is it stores the value at the **ith** row in the **u4** column from your DataFrame using the formula inside the `np.roots` method for all rows in your DataFrame, if that makes sense.

Anyway, let me know if this solves your problem. Thanks :))

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped! Don't forget to click the up arrow. Thank you :)).